# select rows with column that is not null?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

by default I have one column in MySQL table to be NULL.

I want to select some rows but only if the field value in that column is not NULL.

what is the correct way of typing it?

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM names
        WHERE id = 1
        AND name != NULL";
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use:

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM names
        WHERE id = 1
        AND name IS NOT NULL";
```

You must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` when [working with NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that the php integer and the MySQL field type may have different value ranges. So `(int)$id` may be feasible, may be not.

Comment: @VolkerK  I tremble at the sight of unescaped variables going into SQL-bound strings, just raising awareness :)

Comment: is it required to assume $id as integer? i never did such thing, but never meet the problem!!!

Answer (score 8):

```
 AND name IS NOT NULL
```

(NULL comparisons require the special IS and IS NOT operator in SQL)

Comment: Beg pardon, working in a couple of case-insignificant DBMSes this week.  Will edit.

Comment: @Andy: MySQL is case-insensitive for columns'/tables' names.

Comment: @Crozin: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html : "Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names."

Comment: @Crozin it's actually case-insensitive for column names, but *table names* are case sensitive. Apologies.